# Use result from one dataframe to find data in another dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am learning pandas.
I have two dataframe A,B
2 col of data come from A are row and col in B. How could I select the data in B based on A' result.
the A's result should have 2 cols. the first result of A is the col of B and the second is the row of B
Thank you.

I manage to get the result from A now. I am still not full understand the pandas dataframe indexing.

```
raw_eps.loc[ raw_eps.loc[:,'ACT_RPT_CODE'] == BEFORE_MARKET, ('Ticker','DATE') ]
```

the example is dummy data
for example the A's result are as follow:

```
result from A:
    Name      DATE
0      123  10/22/15
2      245  10/27/15
```

The dataframe B is as follow:

```
data in B:
    Date      123   245  789
0   10/22/15  ccc   ddd  odo
1   10/27/15  eee   fff  jdj
1   11/21/15  ttt   www  ppp
```

The result I want is using name and date in A's to find data in B

```
ccc   ddd 
 eee   fff
```

Comment: @albert I manage to get the A's result.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @galaxyan will `245`  be `345`?

Comment: @SIslam sorry, I the data should be 245

Comment: @albert why is the data not MCVE?

Comment: Since it is not a code in the sense of making your problem reproducible. MVCE means something like copy and paste a code snippet you provided in order to get started when trying to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer should be set index for B then flat it.

```
B = B.set_index('Date')
B = B.stack()
res = merge(A,B,on='Date')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
dfa= pd.DataFrame({'name':[123,456],'id':[1,2]})
dfb= pd.DataFrame({123:['aaa','bbb'],456:['lll','jjj'],'id':[1,2]})
```

You can pass the values you want to index by to the `.loc`

```
dfb.loc[:,dfa.name.tolist()]
```

Comment: thank you for the code, but it is only use one col from dfa. my gold is use both cols from A. the date is row index and the name is col index.